# Time Complexity of Python Pycryptodome?

Tags: encryption, time-complexity, aes, big-o, pycryptodome

I am trying to find out PyCryptodome's Time complexity for a paper I'm writing, specifically AES-CBC and XChacha20-Poly1305. The problem is, there is nothing in the documentation regarding the matter and I can't think of a way to measure it by myself by implementing the library. Any thoughts?

Tried reading the documentation and actually implementing it but not luck.

Comment: What would `n` be in something like the time complexity of an AES implementation?

Comment: Why would you expect AES-CBC (or any symmetric encryption algorithm) to have a time complexity other than O(n)? Do you expect encryption time to be non-linear as the input grows?

Comment: Compare AES-CBC and XChacha20-Poly1305? AES-CBC is at most Ind-CPA secure, XChacha20-Poly1305? is AEAD secure> Ind-CCA. Your paper's base is not correct. You should compare  something like AES-CBC-HMAC and XChacha20-Poly1305.